# What is the difference between throwing inside .then block or within async await block?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I get this error:

```
(node:9868) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: #<Object>
(node:9868) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9868) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code
```

I am wrapping the create method with express error handler that looks like this:

```
export const errorHandler = (callback: any) => {
  return (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    callback(req, res, next).catch(next);
  };
};
```

when I try to do this:

```
async create(entity: T){
 this._model
        .findOne({ name: (entity as any).name })
        .then((res) => {

          if (res) {
            throw Exceptions.ENTITY_EXISTS; // doesnt work 
          }
        })
}
```

however when I change it to be async await it works fine

```
async create(entity: T) {
     const res = await this._model.findOne({ name: (entity as any).name });
     if (res) throw Exceptions.ENTITY_EXISTS;
}
```

Also when I tried to do instead of throw `Promise.reject(Exceptions.ENTITY_EXISTS)` it threw the same error.

Can someone explain me the differences between these three, and also why only the async await is working?

Answer (score 3):

The difference is indeed where the `throw` happens. In the working version, it makes the promise returned by `create()` to settle as rejected.

In the non-working version it makes the promise returned by `.then()` to settle as rejected. However this promise is not the one returned by `create()`, and so even if you correctly handle a rejection on `create()`... that doesn't handle the rejection that happened on the `then()` promise. They are not connected, and so you don't handle that rejection.

To fix the first version, make sure to *return* the promise returned by `.then()`:

```
create(entity: T){
    return this._model
//  ^^^^^^
        .findOne({ name: (entity as any).name })
        .then((res) => {
            if (res) {
                throw Exceptions.ENTITY_EXISTS; // doesnt work 
            }
        });
}
```

NB: Although you could keep `async` before the function, it really is not so useful if you don't use `await` and return a promise.

NB2: Because of this missing `return`, the `create` function actually returned a promise that resolved immediately... so it was never awaiting the database query.